# Explain rule in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to follow up on an issue we are having with a site, related to SSL, whereby some of the CSS and JS links are given a port 443 (:443) in their URL by wordpress.

I have found the following lines in the `.htaccess` files - wonder if it's because of that?

Can someone pls explain to me what this is doing?

Thanks in advance

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule .* - [E=WPR_SSL:-https]
```

Comment: Both lines do the same thing : If the request is made using HTTPS  then set the enviornment variable **WPR_SSL** and value **-https**

Comment: @Starkeen - can you make this the answer pls? Thanks!